# Is there a name for AUC interpreted for regression models?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, auc

The AUC can be interpreted as the probability that a classifier will give a higher score for positive examples than negative examples.

What do we call the probability that, for any pair of test examples, a regressor gives a higher score to the test example with the higher value?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a specific name for your concept, but there are close matches. You probably want to compute something like [Kendall's $\tau$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient) on your predicted and actual values, which looks at pairs of data points and is calculated as

[image: Definition of Tau]

A concordant pair is a pair of data points where the regressor gives a higher score and the result actually is higher; a discordant pair is the opposite. This is very close to what you requested, but it is not a probability; $\tau$ will be in the range $[-1, 1]$.

However, if you compute $\frac{\text{number of concordant pairs}}{{n \choose 2}}$ you should get the quantity you want, which is quite close to $\tau$ but should be restricted to the range $[0, 1]$.